# Collapse long lines of output in terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal

I often have very long lines of terminal output with no \ns that are rarely useful and get in the way of finding the output I want (eg error logs or minified files that are matched by ack). Is there a tool that could collapse such long lines? For me the ideal would probably be an indication in the gutter that a line has been collapsed, which could be clicked to expand if I do want to look at the full line. I'm using OS X Terminal but am happy to switch to another tool if it provides this. A workaround that cuts lines off after the terminal width that I could pipe my output to would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of simple solutions. 
To simply truncate lines that are longer than 80 characters, write a script containing

```
#!/bin/sh
expand "$@" | cut -c1-80
```

and pipe your program into it. 
A slightly more sophisticated approach is

```
#!/bin/sh
expand "$@" | awk '{ if (length <= 80) print; else print substr($0,1,77) "...";}'
```

This adds `...` as a marker when it discards data. 
It gives you only the first 77 characters so the `...` itself doesn’t go past the margin.

The `expand` command is used to expand tabs to spaces,
because the `cut` and `awk` commands are simply counting characters,
and would not realize that a line containing more than ten tabs is too long.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `expand`. Presumably I could work `tput cols` in there instead of 80 for variable terminal widths.